# Uncatchable exception in event handler

Tags: javascript, react-redux, rxjs, dom-events

I have a small Chrome extension that injects this line into the Netflix js:

```
netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[1].handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}});
```

Especially note the `dragend[1]`. In some cases this works fine, and in other cases only `dragend[0]` works. If `dragend[1]` works then `dragend[0]` will throw an exception and vice versa. When I wrap a try/catch block around that line, it never works. The catch block is never entered and the exception surfaces back to the browser.

How can I trap the exception? (Note: I cannot find any property values related to that line of code that would suggest whether I should use 0 or a 1.) It seems my only hope is being able to trap the exception, and if I tried 0 and it errors, then try 1, and vice versa.

The error message is usually this:

> Cannot read propert 'target' of null

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the logic decoupled, you can do:

```js
try {
  netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1]
    .scope.events.dragend[0].handler(null, {
      value: 123,
      pointerEventData: {
        playing: true
      }
    })
} catch(e) {
  netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1]
    .scope.events.dragend[1].handler(null, {
      value: 123,
      pointerEventData: {
        playing: true
      }
    })
}
```

#### Explanation:

- The `try` block will catch an exception if `dragend[0]` causes errors

  - In which case the `catch` block ***can not throw an exception***)
- Or vice versa, where the `try` block never sees an exception

  - Thus the `catch` logic is never run

---

### Edit: *The Promise way*

This depends on whether the output of handler is a *`Promise`*. If so then you can do:

```js
const netflixHandler = idx => netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1]
  .scope.events.dragend[idx].handler(null, {
    value: 123,
    pointerEventData: {
      playing: true
    }
  })

netflixHandler(0) //Expecting a Promise
   .catch(_ => netflixHandler(1)) //If failed, then rectify, and continue the chain!
   .then(_ => /*Continue rest of the logic here*/)
```

Comment: AP thanks for the thoughtful answer, but it still doesn't work. The catch block is never reached. I even proved it by putting a console.log(..) at the very top of the catch block. Never reached. I'm 99% sure that something async is going on because it is--after all--dealing with events. So if the error occurs in a separate async thread, that could explain it. But I still have no idea how to handle it in this case. This one is really stumping me.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder can you check if the output of that function is a promise by any chance? If so I may have another solution, that you could give a shot

Comment: There could be a promise involved but I don't know. I'd love to see your other solution.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder Just added it, as long as the output matches the expectation, this would work!

Comment: thanks again...but still no joy. http://zerogravpro.com/temp/promise.png - same error as before, but additionally an error about `catch undefined`.

Comment: That's ok, I went down a different path that works, though would love to someday discover how to catch exceptions in js, in cases like this.